# auto complete jQuery com 2 input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocompletar

Tenho o seguinte autocomplete que funciona no 1º input, ao o completar ele preenche o 2º input.

O problema e que se apago a tag `<p>` ele não funciona. Alguém sabe me dizer o porque?

Segue o código:

```js
$().ready(function() {

  $("#singleBirdRemote").autocomplete("search.php", {
    width: 260,
    selectFirst: false
  });

  $("#singleBirdRemote").result(function(event, data) {
    if (data)
      $(this).parent().next().find("#xx").val(data[0]);
  });

});
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" id="singleBirdRemote">
</p>
<p>
  <input name="asdad" id="xx">
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isso ocorra por você recuperar a referência do segundo input de modo relativo, percorrendo a árvore do DOM.

Ou seja, você se baseia em **#singleBirdRemote**, busca o pai **p**, navega para o próximo elemento e busca pelo input **xx**. Quando remove **p** você quebra essa hierarquia.

```js
 $(this).parent().next().find("#xx").val(data[0]);
```

Pode substituir o trecho simplesmente por

```js
 $("#xx").val(data[0]);
```

Acredito que apenas isso já ajudará.

Tome cuidado ao navegar de modo relativo, qualquer alteração no código poderá te causar problemas. O ideal é ter referências precisas, por id, name ou class, dependendo da necessidade.

Comment: Bom da sua forma não deu certo, eu achei uma solução assim: $(this).parent().find("input[@name=valor]").val(data[3]); o que vc acha?

Comment: Como você aplicou a solução? Aparentemente houve alterações no código, já que existe um name no input e agora você indexa data por 3, não por zero, ou seja, poderia aplicar $("#xx").val(data[3]);

Comment: O problema da solução que usou é que continua utilizando a referência por parent! Isso deve ser evitado, quando possível! Senão seu código fica muito dependente da hierarquia do html!

Comment: ficou assim: https://jsfiddle.net/6gt2z1z8/

Comment: Tente apenas $("input[name=b]").val(data[3]); Tem tudo para funcionar sem depender da hierarquia!

Comment: perfeito, funciona 100%