# autocomplete funciona apenas com jQuery 1.2.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocompletar

Bom estou usando um plugin autocomplete com 2 input, onde coloco o valor em 1 input e o 2º e preenchido. O problema e que meu sistema trabalha com jQuery 1.7.2, pois tenho várias funções com ele. E este auto complete so funciona com jQuery 1.2.6. Como resolvo isso?

Segue meu código:

```js
$().ready(function () {

        $("#singleBirdRemote").autocomplete("search.php", {
            width: 260
        });

        $("#singleBirdRemote").result(function (event, data) {
            if (data) {

                $(this).parent().find("input[@name=b]").val(data[1]);

            }
        });

    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="singleBirdRemote">

    <input name="a" >
    <input name="b" >
    <input name="c" >
```

Comment: Você não precisa do "@" no seletor ! "input[name=b]"!

Comment: E poderia utilizar simplesmente a pergunta anterior http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118778/42575

Comment: o problema era por causa do @ vlw

Comment: coloca a solução como resposta aqui pra vc dar o "check" verde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproduzindo o comentário:

Você não precisa do "@" no seletor, use simplesmente

```
input[name=b]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução foi remover o @

```
$(this).parent().find("input[@name=b]").val(data[1]);
```